# Configured Eclipse with pyDev for running black and isort and it is not doing either since the latest Eclipse update

Tags: isort

I have isort selected like this:
[image] and black is configured like this: [image], but since the last Eclipse update, they are not formatting and sorting my code any more

Even keeping one line between the methods and two empty lines between the functions and classes is not adjusted. Same goes for "a=b", which used to be changed to "a = b"

I was checking my configuration for anything that would help with this, but couldn't find anything there. Right now, I have no other ideas what to do to fix this